# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}\displaystyle H_{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\displaystyle H_{n}$ be the harmonic number s.t. $\displaystyle H_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$.

Show the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}\displaystyle H_{n}$ converge or diverge.

**Thoughts** I know  that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$ converge and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n$ diverges to $\infty$, but maybe bounded(?). Tried to use Dirichlet's test but didn't worked for me.

Comment: Show that $n\mapsto H_n/n$ decreases (and then apply Dirichlet's test).

Comment: If you are interested in finding the closed form: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n) H_n}{n}=\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(e^i)^n H_n}{n}=\Im\left(\frac12\ln^2(1-e^i)+\text{Li}_2(e^i)\right)$$

$$=\frac{1-\pi}{2}\ln(2\sin(1/2))+\Im\, \text{Li}_2(e^i)\approx1.05895$$

Answer (score 2):

You may apply Dirichlet's test/summation by parts in the following way:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(n)\frac{H_n}{n} = \frac{H_N}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(n)+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin(k)\right)\left(\frac{H_{n}}{n}-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}\right) \tag{1}$$
We have that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(n)$ is bounded and $\frac{H_N}{N}\sim\frac{\log N}{N}$ converges to zero as $N\to +\infty$. Moreover
$$ \frac{H_n}{n}-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\ll\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
so the second term in $(1)$ is absolutely convergent and the initial series is convergent.

Comment: Can you explain the inequation $\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\ll\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ ?

Comment: @G.Ticher: well, $1/(n+1)^2\ll 1/n^{3/2}$ is trivial, so you only need $H_n\sim\log(n)\ll\sqrt{n}$, which is simple.

Comment: It's not needed, but $\ln(n) = O(n^c)$ for any $c > 0$ (big or little oh doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

Habitually, we aren't given context, so we can't know if it's just about the mere fact of convergence, or if the numerical value of the sum might matter.
So this is about the numerical value of the sum mentioned by the OP, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}\displaystyle H_{n},$$
not a trivial matter, because:
While the fact of convergence was pointed out, the speed of convergence is very poor, so we may be in need of some algebra/analysis. It's well known that $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,\frac{z^n}{n}=\log{\frac1{1-z}},$$
and thus $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,H_n\,z^n=\frac1{1-z}\,\log{\frac1{1-z}}.$$
Dividing by $z$ and integrating (and using $\frac1{z(1-z)}=\frac1z+\frac1{1-z}$), we arrive at
$$f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,\frac{H_n}n\,z^n=\frac12\,\log^2\frac1{1-z}+\operatorname{Li}_2(z).$$
We're interested in the imaginary part of $f(e^{i})$, because the imaginary part of $e^{n\,i}$ is $\sin n$. So we don't even need  Mathematica, just [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=imaginary%20part%20of%200.5*%28log%281-e%5Ei%29%29%5E2%2Bdilog%28e%5Ei%29).
The result is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}\displaystyle H_{n}=1.0589534648523103492273504832032055125828186921473547259826$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).